# What does Microsoft recommend for 2nd level Caching in Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, caching, entity-framework-5, data-access-layer

I've used "[EF Provider Wrappers](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=4747)" made by Jarek Kowalski. It works fine but I noticed "Limitations and Disclaimers" section where it says:

> *The providers have not been extensively tested beyond what’s included in the sample code, so **you should use them at your own risk.***
>
> *As with any other sample, **Microsoft is not offering any kind of support for it**, but if you find bugs or have feature suggestions, please use this blog’s contact form and let me know about them.*

I'm little confused here, Does Microsoft really expect developers to use EnityFramework on production websites without any official support (or recommendation) for 2nd level Caching?

Comment: The title seems a little aggressive. Instead of going on "the attack", consider asking for the desired goal e.g.: What is a supported 2nd Level Caching strategy for EF? (The first impression can make a big difference to responses and/or close votes ..)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no official 2nd level cache support. I'm even not sure if EF Provider wrappers are compatible with .NET 4.5. 2nd level cache [is in backlog](http://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1015353-support-for-second-level-cache) for future versions of EF.

You can also implement your own solution because [EF is fully open sourced](http://entityframework.codeplex.com/).

Btw. I have seen dozens of quite complex web sites running in production without any cache ...

Comment: Thanks Ladislav, There are small issues in EF Provider wrappers in for Entity Framework 5 which are fixable.

Comment: 'Send us a patch'. Great approach from the worlds largest software company.

Answer (score 9):

There is now a 2nd level cache provider available for EF 6.x

> Entity Framework does not currently support caching of query results. A sample EF Caching provider is available for Entity Framework version 5 and earlier but due to changes to the provider model this sample provider does not work with Entity Framework 6 and newer. This project is filling the gap by enabling caching of query results for Entity Framework 6.1 applications.

https://github.com/moozzyk/EFCache

And Redis provider implemented on top of it :

> Extends EFCache by adding Redis support
>
> I wanted to add L2 Cache to EF using Redis - there was nothing
>   available at the time.
>
> I found EFCache written by Pawel Kadluczka (moozzyk) over on CodePlex

https://github.com/silentbobbert/EFCache.Redis

Answer (score 2):

Apache Ignite.NET provides a distributed in-memory 2nd level cache for Entity Framework: https://apacheignite-net.readme.io/docs/entity-framework-second-level-cache